# Pivoting Longer in R to create more than one value column

Tags: r

First of all let me apologise if any of this is super basic or unclear - I'm very new to R, and struggling with something which seems as though it should be a very thing.

I have a fairly large dataset (data frame read in from a csv), and at the moment each individual is represented by a single row, with multiple observations (the columns). A simplified version would look something like this:

```
id <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")
hrar1 <- c(21, 22, 22, 41)
hrar2 <- c(24, 32, 33, 42)
hrar3 <- c(27, 35, 39, 51)
pai1 <- c(103, 103, 103, 103)
pai2 <- c(115, 115, 115, 115)
pai3 <- c(127, 127, 127, 127)

df <- data.frame(id, hrar1, hrar2, hrar3, pai1, pai2, pai3)
```

I am trying to correlate the change in hrar value with the increase in pai value. So I believe I need to reorganise the data to be in long format. Looking something more like this:

```
id2 <- c("1", "1", "1",  
         "2", "2", "2",  
         "3", "3", "3",  
         "4", "4", "4")
hrar <- c(21, 24, 27,
        22, 32, 35,
        22, 33, 39,
        41, 42, 51)
pai <- c(103, 115, 127,
         103, 115, 127,
         103, 115, 127,
         103, 115, 127)

df2 <- data.frame(id2, pai, hrar)
```

So all the values from the 'paixxx' columns in the original data frame have been gathered and the corresponding 'hrarxxx' value is next to it.

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to use the pivot_longer() function to do this. The new column (what I think is the 'names()' column), is not in the existing names of the data frame as per the examples I can find online, but is instead in the actual cell.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried lots of different things, all using the pivot_longer() function, all of which throw errors... I have been using the online resources I can find, but don't seem to be able to find anything which helps me understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using the special `".value"` and the `names_pattern` argument of `pivot_longer` you could do:

```r
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c(".value", "id2"), names_pattern = "(.*?)(\\d+)")
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    id    id2    hrar   pai
#>    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1     1        21   103
#>  2 1     2        24   115
#>  3 1     3        27   127
#>  4 2     1        22   103
#>  5 2     2        32   115
#>  6 2     3        35   127
#>  7 3     1        22   103
#>  8 3     2        33   115
#>  9 3     3        39   127
#> 10 4     1        41   103
#> 11 4     2        42   115
#> 12 4     3        51   127
```

**EDIT**

What we want to achieve is to reshape the dataset such that we end up with one column `hrar` containing the values of `hrar1` to  `hrar3` and one column `pai` containing the values of `pai1` to  `pai3`.

First using `".value"` we tell `pivot_longer` that we want multiple value columns and one `name` column (which I called `id2`). Or put differently we want to split the names of the columns we pivot in two parts. Using `c(".value", "id2")` we tell `pivot_longer` that the first part should become the name of the value column(s) and the second part the category of the name column.

Second we have to tell `pivot_longer` how to split the column names into two parts. That is done via the `names_pattern` argument using regular expressions. Here the `()` are used to define the two parts. The `(\\d+)` means that the second part consists only of digits. The `(.?*)` means that the first group consists of all characters to the left of the digits, e.g. using these patterns `hrar3` gets splitted into `hrar` and `3`.

Finally, the `id2` column contains the information on the value's origin, i.e. whether the `hrar` value is from `hrar2` or `hrar3`. If this is not needed you can drop that column or assign a more suitable name than `id2`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It works on the example that I gave, but then I can't translate that to the actual data set for some reason - perhaps because I don't understand the syntax or either ".value" or "(.*)(\\d+)" would you be able to explain this a little or point me towards where I can find an explanation? The other thing is that "id" and "id2" are also equivalent, I just gave them separate variable names while creating the data frames.

Comment: I just made an edit with some explanations on the syntax. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Oh yes, that does help loads. Thanks so much, that's very clear and working now.